# express-validator with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm developing my own website using (angularjs, bootstrap) for front end (node, express) for back end (mongodb, mongoose layer) for the database.
I have a registration form and in that form I want to check that the email hasn't already been taken when someone try to create new account, so I want my registration api to check if the submitted email hasn't already  been taken before.

I'm now using this validator 
https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#validation-by-schema and this is my code :

```
var vadlidateRegUser= function (req,res,next) {
req.checkQuery('UserName','Username must contain letters and numbers only').isAlphanumeric().notEmpty();

req.checkQuery('Email','Email should have a valid syntax e.g: example@example.com')
    .isEmail().notEmpty();

var error = req.validationErrors();
if(!error){
next();
}else {
  res.json({success:false, message:error});
}

}
```

Now I would like to check with the validator if email is unique, something like this:

```
req.checkQuery('Email','Email should have a valid syntax e.g: example@example.com')
    .isEmail().isUnique(Model Name);
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: What is your issue/question?

Comment: sorry updated .

Comment: doesn't isEmail check if it valid email or not ... i can't get you ?

Comment: No it just checks for syntax , I want it to check in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*express-validator* can check and sanitize your input data but can't tell if an email is already in your database.

Best way I think is to make it `unique` in your *mongoose* Schema and handle error when email already exist.:

```
let User = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,  // ensure unique email
        validate: [ isEmail, "Email should have a valid syntax e.g: example@example.com" ]
    },
    // ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much , but is this the best practice ?! what if I made my custom rules ?!

Comment: You're welcome.I think it is an easy and clean solution but I'll be glad to hear other expert opinion. If you really want do this with _express-validation_, you can make your own [customValidators](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#customvalidators), but I think that is less effective as you'll have to make a database query to check if the email already exists.

Comment: Thank you for your help , I will take your advice and I'm going to make it with mongoose validator.

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles upon this solution, [read this first](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator). mongoose `unique` may not do what you think it does.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that two users will try to sign up with the same email at exactly the same time @JamesLemieux. I don't use unique as a validator in this solution, but as an unique index.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but i found it today hoping to help me with the same problem but I managed to find a way to do it, so I wanted to share it for the next one to find it.

Now express-validator has the ability to check with Promises.

What I did was to create a seperate file with my mongoose schema and require it in my router, then during my checks i did this:

```
check('email').custom((value) => {

    var query = User.find({ email: value})
    return query.exec().then(user => {
        if (user.length > 0) {
             return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
        }
    });
}),
```

and everything works like a charm!

I hope this helps someone else. 
If you need more specifics, just reply so I can add more detail.